# Checking Datareader and Connection object NULL in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I want to convert the following C# code into VB.NET

```
        if (dr != null)
            dr.Close();
        if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            con.Close();
        dr = null;
```

In VB.NET,I am not finding any suitable method or approach to check and  if the OracleDatareader and OracleConnection object is NULL. How I can interpret the above code in VB.NET? I am using System.Data.OrcleClient namespace to access data from Orcale database.

Comment: Looking at the code above I would recommend you *not* copy it verbatim. Instead use `using` blocks in your vb.net or c# code to ensure types that implement `IDisposable` free up their external resources. See [Using Statement - VB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vb.net `!=null` becomes `IsNot Nothing` and `&&` becomes `andAlso`. We need to use AndAlso to be able to get the short circuiting like in the second if statement. Finally, `==` is just `=`.

Therefore the end result is:

```vb
        If dr IsNot Nothing Then
            dr.Close()
        ElseIf con IsNot Nothing AndAlso con.State = ConnectionState.Open then
            con.Close()
        End If
        dr = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.